# MVC core MSI builder, how to create installer?

Tags: c#, deployment, wix, windows-installer, asp.net-core-mvc

I've written an MVC core app. The next step is to wrap it in an MSI and distribute it to clients. The problem is this: I can't seem to find any built in way capture all the content files and dll's automatically and wrap them in an MSI. I've tried so far windows installer and wix (heat, to be precise) and both of them doesn't seem to have a built in way to work with .net core. Did Microsoft just decided it's not important enough or am I missing something important? I could try to put all the output and all the dependencies, file by file, but that would be hell to maintain, with the new Nuget approach there are many many dll's required for a project, together with all the content it becomes enormous. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: A very interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still adjusting to this "modern" world and part of me wonders why you'd want to package a .NET core app as an MSI.  I'd think you'd be running it in a docker container or windows server app (appx) in the "cloud" or on nano server which doesn't even support MSI.   For  actual windows servers I'd assume regular old .NET. (Which I still fondly love.)

That said, I have an open source program called IsWiX (CodePlex) and have a very simple pattern for creating ASP.NET website installers (see video at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgDf1kv8a-4)   and I'd be willing to work with you to come up with a similiar story for asp.net-core mvc apps.

From what I read, .net core apps also have msbuild publish profile support.  That is what I use to create the model from which I author my installers.  From there I just drag drop my files into IsWiX and let it author all the XML for me.

FWIW website installers have always had a lot of files.  Even before nuget and npm a website developer might add a few thousand files to their project just by adding say Infragistics. I once worked on an installer with over 300,000 files.  Yikes! I always wished we had a way of just creating an uncompresssed archive of this stuff and IIS could see if as a directory but to my knowledge that never happened.

The MSI world is a declarative world where we need to explicitly list each of those files.   Web developers live in a world where they just say "publish" and don't care about those details.  That is the gap that I try to bridge with IsWiX.

Comment: Wow, if would only know about your tool a few days ago... I ended up doing something almost similar, I've published my project using msbuild publish profile and created a simple winform app to parse the target folder for me and construct the xml for wix. Thank you very much for the reply and for the project. About your first paragraph, I know that the modern approach is towards "cloud" solutions, but sometimes organizations, which not always allow internet access, just need to install a simple web service on one server and it needs to be shipped in a familiar way. Modern shmodern.

Comment: Ya the "modern" crowd only see it the new way. I'm still trying to see the different ways of doing it to mix some old school into the new school.  If there is common story of  I want to take an asp.net core app and deploy it with an MSI and configure IIS as a reverse proxy then I'd love to understand that and create a template for it.   You can help me understand the parts I don't yet understand.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis explains how to publish ASP.Net Core app to IIS. All it needs is .Net Core Windows Server Hosting and VC++ 2015 redistributable. I can help you to build the template.

Comment: @user2033402 You mentioned - "_I've published my project using msbuild publish profile and created a simple winform app to parse the target folder for me and construct the xml for wix_". **Can you please share your steps?**

Comment: Someone asked about this on the wix-users list recently. I'd still like to work on this with someone.  I'll create a github repos in a bit and start framing it up.

Comment: @Vishal26 i can, but why not use CristopherPainter's tool? This is what I would use having known about it in advanced. No point developing what someone else have already developed. but the steps are: hitting right click on the project, press publish->create a custom publish profile to a folder in file system-> make a winform\console app that parses the published folder and put it in wix xml structure-> put this xml in your product.wxs file. I  can share the code but it's redundant since Christopher did the same thing better and its open source

Comment: @ChristopherPainter as much as I would love to, I'm already involved in both a regular job and my own startup. I don't have the time to participate in open source projects which are not directly linked with any of them. Sorry

Comment: I've already worked it out.  Also it seems like this is directly related to answering your question and deploying your application.